# Chrome browser is not open in selenium using linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, eclipse

i have setup eclipse and setup require jar file. i want to just open browser using selenium. but it display error 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi have you downloaded chrome driver for linux ?

Comment: yes i have download

Comment: I think there are latest version available for chromedriver. Download it and replace with your current one. Then also try update chrome browser and use it.

Comment: i have replace update version but still getting error

Comment: Update selenium 3.4.0 and chromedriver latest

Comment: I think this issue is being come from multiple version conflicting with browsers. Sometimes we need to identify best pair of working things

Comment: i have update that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61536/discussion-between-sagar007-and-rutvi-soni).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible error :**

1. Old configurations
2. Already chromedriver process is open and occupied port

**Solution :**

> **1.  Use latest files :**

- Java 8
- Selenium 3.4.0 ([Latest one](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/))
- Chromedriver ([Latest one](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/))

  *Note : Clean your project before use.*

> **2. Sometimes already opened `chromedriver` process blocked the ports :**

- Run command to kill all process related to chrome browser in terminal:

  ```
      killall chrome
      killall chromedriver
  ```

  *Note : Name of the process would be same as given in `chromedriver`. Here `chrome` is process name.*

Answer (score 0):

- Java 8
- Selenium 3.4.0

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.4.0

- Chromedriver 2.32

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/

- Chromium v61

Linux x64: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/

Windows x64: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/487842/